# Given bounded stopping times for $(F_n)$, how do we show that $(X_n, F_n)$ is a submartingale?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, self-learning, martingales, stopping-times

> Let $\{X_n\,:\,n=1,2,...\}$ be a sequence of random variables. Define
> \begin{align*}
> F_n=\sigma(X_1,X_2,...,X_n).
> \end{align*}
> Suppose that for any bounded stopping times $\sigma\le\tau$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> EX_\sigma\le EX_\tau,\quad\text{a.s.}
> \end{align*}
> Prove that $(X_n, F_n)$ is a submartingale.

Unfortunately I don't have any preliminary work for this one, I know multiple theorems about stopping times for martingales but they $\textbf{assume}$ that the $X_n$ already make up a martingale. So, I am at a loss for how to even begin this one, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My thought is to use Doob-Meyer decomposition for discrete time, which can be derived from stopping time theorem. However you have to show first that $X_n$ is a martingale.

Comment: And also this fact could be useful: If $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are bounded stopping times a.s. and $\sigma\leq\tau$, and if $X_n$ is a martingale, then $\mathbb{E} X_1=\mathbb{E} X_\sigma=\mathbb{E} X_\tau=\mathbb{E} X_n$. This is just my general idea for this problem.

Comment: Fix times $m<n$ and an event $A$ in $F_m$. You need to show that $E[X_m; A]\le E[X_n; A]$. This suggests the use of the stopping times 
$$
\sigma(\omega):=\cases{m,& $\omega\in A$,\cr n,&$\omega\notin A$,\cr}
$$
and $\tau\equiv n$. Your task: (1) show that $\sigma$ *is* a stopping time; (2) evaluate $E(X_\sigma)$ and $E(X_\tau)$.